# Javascript: Saving indexes of duplicate items in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I created this function to find duplicate entries in a web form, what I need is to store the index numbers of each duplicated item in another array..to

```
function arrTieneDups( arr ) 
{                          
    var xi, xj, xn;
    n=arr.length;

    for (xi=0; xi<n; xi++) {                        
        for (xj=xi+1; xj<n; xj++) {              
            if (arr[xi]==arr[xj]) return true;
    }   }
    return false;
}
```

loop through that new array and use it as well..

```
for (var i in arr2)
{
    $( "input[name$='matricula"+i+"']" ).addClass("errorformalta");
    $( "input[name$='matricula"+i+"']" ).addClass("errorinputtext"); 
    $( "input[name$='matricula"+i+"']" ).after('<span style="display: inline; margin-left: -20px; opacity: 1;font-size:48px;color:red;font-weight:800;" class="pyr_error_form">!</span>');
}
```

I am now doing as well..through the Orcuro code. But the result is not as expected. I need "var it" to be the index number of repeated items. e.g: 2,4,6
What I want is, indicate to the user the fields where they have introduced repeated data.

```
for (var it in arrTieneDups(matriculas) )
{
  $( "input[name$='matricula"+it+"']" ).addClass("errorformalta");
  $( "input[name$='matricula"+it+"']" ).addClass("errorinputtext"); 
  $( "input[name$='matricula"+it+"']" ).after('<span style="display: inline; margin-left: -20px; opacity: 1;font-size:48px;color:red;font-weight:800;" class="pyr_error_form">!</span>');
  error_validation=1;
  error_top=1;
  error_mat_formato="</br>! Matrícula(s) inválida(s)";
  error_look="</br>Revise también los siguientes errores:";
  all_ok=1;
}
```

Comment: you can try using map: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: *"index numbers of each duplicated item"* - just the index of duplicate, or the indces of the original and it's duplicate.? Please provide sample input and output.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I need the index numbers of each duplicated item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass this "duplicate object" array as a parameter. Something like...

```
 function arrTieneDups( arr ) 
 {                          
    var xi, xj;
    var dupeArray = [];
    n=arr.length;

    for (xi=0; xi<n; xi++) {                        
        for (xj=xi+1; xj<n; xj++) {              
            if (arr[xi]==arr[xj]) 
                dupeArray.push(arr [xi]);
    }   }
    return dupeArray;
}
```

From there,  outside your function,  iterate over this array and add the necessary styles as you were before.

```
for (var i in  arrTieneDups( yourArray ) )
{
    $( "input[name$='matricula"+i+"']" ).addClass("errorformalta");
    $( "input[name$='matricula"+i+"']" ).addClass("errorinputtext"); 
    $( "input[name$='matricula"+i+"']" ).after('<span style="display: inline; margin-left: -20px; opacity: 1;font-size:48px;color:red;font-weight:800;" class="pyr_error_form">!</span>');
}
```

Syntax might be off. I have no way of testing right now.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input code. But .. How do I call the function ?. Before I was doing so, if ( arrTieneDups( matriculas ) ) .So, the function was called when it found duplicates.

Comment: I would call the function within the for() loop parameters. The loop won't iterate if the array returned from arrTieneDups is empty.
I've altered my code to closer-reflect your original design - arrays holding indexes. I hope it's at least somewhat helpful.
However, I would still be inclined, since you are using jQuery already, to add the actual objects to an array and alter them that way. Without seeing how you get your original `arr` that you pass to your function, I can't really advise how to go about this.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest instead of returning true when finding a duplicate to simply store that index (xi in your case) to duplicates array and after the loop return that array.

also variable xn is not used anywhere from what i see here